# Why is one expression valid while the other is not?

Tags: haskell

My definition starts this way:

```
isPalindrome' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome' [] = True
isPalindrome' [_] = True
```

Adding one more line to this definition, one approach throws errors while the other works fine.

Works:

```
isPalindrome' xs = head xs == last xs && (isPalindrome' $ init $ tail xs)

isPalindrome' xs = head xs == last xs && isPalindrome' ( init $ tail xs)
```

Fails:

```
isPalindrome' xs = head xs == last xs && isPalindrome' $ init $ tail xs
```

I don't understand why this fails.

Doesn't `isPalindrome' $ init $ tail xs` mean the same thing as `isPalindrome' ( init ( tail xs))`?

Comment: I suspect this is a problem with precedence: your failing expression is probably being grouped as `head xs == (last xs && isPalindrome') $ init $ tail xs` or something similarly incorrect. But I haven’t memorised the Haskell operator precedence table, so I can’t be entirely sure.

Answer (score 2):

Your failing expression

```
isPalindrome' xs = head xs == last xs && isPalindrome' $ init $ tail xs
```

is actually parsed / iterpreted / by Haskell as

```
isPalindrome' xs = ((head xs == last xs) && isPalindrome') (init (tail xs))
```

and this obviously isn't good.

How can we tell that it is parsed that way? Using the `:i` command we discover

```
> :i &&
infixr 3 &&

> :i ==
infix 4 ==

> :i $
infixr 0 $
```

`==`'s precedence is 4 so it is higher than `&&`'s (which is 3), so it binds its operands first, and thus `(head xs == last xs)` expression is formed. Then, `&&`'s precedence 3 is higher than `$`'s 0, so `&&` binds *its* operands and thus `((head xs == last xs) && isPalindrome')` expression is formed. Then `$` gets to work, which does associate on the right.

Another way to see this is through error messages (which you should always include in questions):

```
> isPalindrome' xs = head xs == last xs && isPalindrome' $ init $ tail xs

<interactive>:184:24:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a] -> t' with actual type `Bool'
    Relevant bindings include 
         ..............
         ..............

<interactive>:184:46:
    Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `[a] -> t'
    Relevant bindings include
      xs :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:184:19)
      isPalindrome' :: [a] -> t (bound at <interactive>:184:5)
    Probable cause: isPalindrome' is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of `(&&)', namely isPalindrome'
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    In the expression: head xs == last xs && isPalindrome'
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So we can see here how  it was parsed, and that `&&` was interpreted as the top operator in this expression.

The reason `isPalindrome' xs = head xs == last xs && isPalindrome' ( init $ tail xs)` works is that the "space" after `isPalindrome'` i.e. the application by juxtaposition has the highest possible "precedence" in Haskell.